# How to display before/after hook in Allure report using mocha-allure-reporte?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, allure

In case when the `before` hook failed and all tests in the `describe()` doesn't run in Allure report I don't see `before()` and `after()` hooks, but I need to understand what happened.

Example:

---

```
    before(function () {
        try {
            throw new Error("Error");
        } catch (e) {
            this.skip();
        }
    });

    it('Test 1', function() {

    });

    it('Test 2', function() {

    });

});
```

Example of allure report:

[image: Example of allure report]

Comment: any luck figuring it out? I'm trying to not have my ```before()``` show up on the allure test report

Comment: @DavidTrinh, unfortunately, no. I didn't find any suggestions about how to display before/after hooks in the Allure reporter. But according to your message, I assume that you have the opposite problem (`before/after` hooks displayed in your report and you can't hide it)?